# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dom' of null CQ - extjs

Tags: extjs, adobe, aem

I am getting " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dom' of null" error in the console, not sure what is wrong with the following code.
Any help is appreciated.

```
 <div id='fi-form'></div>
 <script>
    CQ.Ext.onReady( function(){


    var card = new CQ.Ext.Panel({
         applyTo : 'fi-form',
         title: 'Example Wizard',
         layout:'form',
         activeItem: 0, 
          bodyStyle: 'padding:15px',
          defaults: {
              // applied to each contained panel
             border:false
           },
      // the panels (or "cards") within the layout

     items: [{
    id: 'card-0',
    xtype: 'fileuploadfield',
    fieldLabel: 'Photo',
    name: 'photo-path',
    buttonCfg: ' '

 }]
});

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of your empty `buttonCfg` property. Remove it and you shouldn't be seeing this error anymore.

In case you are using CQ 5.5 and above, then it is preferrable to use [html5fileuploadfield](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.html5.form.FileUploadField) instead.

```
<div id='fi-form'></div>
<script>
    CQ.Ext.onReady( function(){
        var card = new CQ.Ext.Panel({
            applyTo : 'fi-form',
            title: 'Example Wizard',
            layout:'form',
            activeItem: 0, 
            bodyStyle: 'padding:15px',
            defaults: {
                // applied to each contained panel
                border:false
            },
            // the panels (or "cards") within the layout
            items: [{
                id: 'card-0',
                xtype: 'html5fileuploadfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Photo',
                name: 'photo-path'
            }]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I upvoted and accepted as the issue is due to buttonCfg empty property as you said. But still this fileuploadfield storing the only one file at the below the page content. If upload a new file, then it is overwriting the existing file. How to have multiple files stored at a content/dam location rather than page content location,